# How to get a parameter and send it with data in the same request in c#

Tags: c#, post, authentication, httpwebrequest, token

I have a page that generate a code (token) for every reload attempt. So the first idea was to create 2 WebClient object, the former to get the code and the second to send the code to the same page with other post parameters. The problem is that it can't work because in the second request, the code (token) will be different from the first one, so it will be wrong. How can I get the token and send it with other parameters in a single request in order to make it legit?

First request:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
request.Accept = "*/*";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Method = "GET";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0";
request.Timeout = 10000;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    re_id = response.Headers.Get("req_id");
}

string token = getBetween(html, "name=\"token\" value=\"", "\" ");
```

Second request

```
HttpWebRequest login = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
login.CookieContainer = cookies;
login.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
login.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
login.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br");
login.Headers.Add("Accept-Language","it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
login.KeepAlive = true;
login.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36";
login.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
login.Headers.Add("req_id", re_id);
login.Method = "POST";
login.Timeout = 10000;

string postData = "myparameters=toset&token=" + token;  
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);  

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
login.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;  

Stream dataStream = login.GetRequestStream ();  
dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);  
dataStream.Close ();  

WebResponse resp = login.GetResponse ();  
Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)resp).StatusDescription);  
dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream ();  
StreamReader read = new StreamReader (dataStream);  

string responseFromServer = read.ReadToEnd ();  
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);   

read.Close ();  
dataStream.Close ();  
resp.Close ();
```

Comment: Fast answer: you cannot. Once you send the request, it is sent, you cannot do anything else. It seems that the website was built this way on purpose to disallow this kind of use

Comment: I saw program that were able to do that. How did they do, maybe with async requests?

Comment: No, that's not possible at all. Maybe you are not passing in the received token correctly